# Changing Top of Bars in Bar Chart to Triangles-Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I am trying to have the tops of the bars in my bar chart be triangles that I can specify the slope of the hypotenuse of. The entire bar needs to be a trapezoid. I am new to javascript and chart.js

I have read a bunch of posts about creating rounded rectangle bars but I don't understand how to adapt the code to my situation. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation about it or on SO.

```
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};


// draws a rectangle with a rounded top
Chart.helpers.drawRoundedTopRectangle = function(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    // top right corner
    ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    // bottom right   corner
    ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
    // bottom left corner
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
    // top left   
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    ctx.closePath();
  };

  Chart.elements.RoundedTopRectangle = Chart.elements.Rectangle.extend({
    draw: function() {
      var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
      var vm = this._view;
      var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped;
      var borderWidth = vm.borderWidth;

      if (!vm.horizontal) {
        // bar
        left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
        right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
        top = vm.y;
        bottom = vm.base;
        signX = 1;
        signY = bottom > top? 1: -1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
      } else {
        // horizontal bar
        left = vm.base;
        right = vm.x;
        top = vm.y - vm.height / 2;
        bottom = vm.y + vm.height / 2;
        signX = right > left? 1: -1;
        signY = 1;
        borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'left';
      }

      // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
      // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
      if (borderWidth) {
        // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
        var barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
        borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize? barSize: borderWidth;
        var halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
        // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
        var borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left'? halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right'? -halfStroke * signX: 0);
        var borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top'? halfStroke * signY: 0);
        var borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom'? -halfStroke * signY: 0);
        // not become a vertical line?
        if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
          top = borderTop;
          bottom = borderBottom;
        }
        // not become a horizontal line?
        if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
          left = borderLeft;
          right = borderRight;
        }
      }

      // calculate the bar width and roundess
      var barWidth = Math.abs(left - right);
      var roundness = this._chart.config.options.barRoundness || 0.5;
      var radius = barWidth * roundness * 0.5;

      // keep track of the original top of the bar
      var prevTop = top;

      // move the top down so there is room to draw the rounded top
      top = prevTop + radius;
      var barRadius = top - prevTop;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
      ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

      // draw the rounded top rectangle
      Chart.helpers.drawRoundedTopRectangle(ctx, left, (top - barRadius + 1), barWidth, bottom - prevTop, barRadius);

      ctx.fill();
      if (borderWidth) {
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      // restore the original top value so tooltips and scales still work
      top = prevTop;
    },
  });


Chart.defaults.roundedBar = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.bar);

Chart.controllers.roundedBar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
  dataElementType: Chart.elements.RoundedTopRectangle
});


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'roundedBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Students',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(143, 53, 83, 1)',
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
      ]
    }, {
      label: 'Teachers',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(143, 53, 83, 1)',
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
      ]
    }, {
      label: 'Visitors',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(143, 53, 83, 1)',
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    barRoundness: 1,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js - Bar Chart with Rounded Tops (drawRoundedTopRectangle Method)"
    },
  }
});
```

This code does a great job creating round bars but I need the entire bar to be a trapezoid with the point of the bar on the right edge of each bar